Как создать синтаксический анализатор на С++
как создать программу на С++, которая переводила, например, бы этот текст:
main(form(text(hello())text1(new)))

в этот:
main form text hello 
main form text1 new

я уже пытался это сделать, но пока не получилось:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string code = "main(form(text(hello(world))text1(new)))";

            vector<string> real_code;
            string token;

            for(char k: code)
            {
                if(k == '(')
                {
                    real_code.push_back(token);
                    real_code.push_back("(");
                    token = "";
                }else if(k == ')')
                {
                    real_code.push_back(token);
                    real_code.push_back(")");
                    token = "";
                }else{token += k;}
            }

    for(string j: real_code)
    {
        cout << j << " ";
    }cout << endl << endl;

    vector<string> names;

    for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    {
        string here = real_code[i];
        string next = (i < 10)? real_code[i+1] : real_code[i];

        cout << "\n=> ";
        if(here == ")")
        {
            for(string j: names)
            {
                cout << j << " ";
            }//cout << endl;
            names.pop_back();
        } else if(here == "("){
            continue;
        } else {
            if(next == ")")
            {
                names.push_back(here);
                for(string j: names)
                {
                    cout << j << " ";
                }
            }
            if(next == "(")
            {
                names.push_back(here);
            }
        }
    }
}

(Заранее простите за говнокод)

Скорее всего это лексический анализатор(по крайней мере, если вы делаете компилятор)

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<string> parseInput(const string& input) {
    vector<string> result;
    string current;
    
    for (char c : input) {
        if (c == '(' || c == ')') {
            if (!current.empty()) {
                result.push_back(current);
                current.clear();
            }
        } else {
            current += c;
        }
    }
    
    if (!current.empty()) {
        result.push_back(current);
    }
    
    return result;
}

void printParsed(const vector<string>& parsed) {
    vector<string> stack;
    
    for (const string& token : parsed) {
        if (!token.empty()) {
            stack.push_back(token);
            for (const string& s : stack) {
                cout << s << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    string input = "main(form(text(hello())text1(new)))";
    vector<string> parsed = parseInput(input);
    printParsed(parsed);
    
    return 0;
}

Вывод:
main form 
main form text 
main form text hello 
main form text1 
main form text1 new 



добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Вам потребуются следующие заголовки: vector, optional*, string и iostream.
Пусть у нас будет перечисление
enum class TokenType
{
    ident,
    open_par,
    close_par,
}

Теперь у нас есть перечисление токенов, вы можете добавлять туда нужные вам типы токенов, пока что я добавил только, те которые были нужны вам сейчас.
Пусть у нас будет структура токена
struct Token
{
    std::optional<std::string> value;
    TokenType type;
}

Пусть у нас есть функция для преобразования токенов в строку.
std::string token_to_string(Token token)
{
    if(token.type == TokenType::ident)
        return token.value.value(); 
    else if(token.type == TokenType::open_pra)
        return " "; 
    else
        return "";
}

Теперь вы можете добавлять или изменять вывод текста. Допустим вы захотите, чтобы open_pra был текст, допустим (, а не пробел. Тогда вам надо просто заменить " " на "("
Теперь пусть будет обратная функция для преобразования строки в токен
Token string_to_token(std::string str)
{
    Token token;

    if(str == "(")
    {
        toke.type = TokenType::open_pra;
    }

    else if(str == ")")
    {
        token.type = TokenType::close_pra;
    }
    
    else
    {
        token.type = TokenType::ident;
        token.value = str;
    }

    return token;
}

Вы также можете расширять эту функцию по мере расширения перечисления.
Теперь самое главное - превращение кода в токены. За это будет отвечать функция tokenizer.
std::vector<Token> tokenizer(std::string code)
{
    std::vector<Token> tokens;
    std::string buffer;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < code.size(); i++)
    {
        char symbol = code.at(i);

        if(std::isalpha(symbol))
        {
           buffer.push_back(symbol);
           i++;

           while(i < code.size() && std::isalnum(code.at(i)))
           {
               buffer.push_back(code.at(i));
               i++;
           }
           i--;

           tokens.push_back(string_to_token(buffer));
           buffer.clear();
        }

        else if(symbol == '(')
        {
            tokens.push_back(Token{.value = "(", .type = TokenType::open_pra});                
        }

        else if(symbol == ')')
        {
            tokens.push_back(Token{.value = ")", .type = TokenType::close_pra});
        }

        else 
        {
            // Можете добавить свой обработчик ошибок при не определённой лексеме, всё же ответы не об этом
            std::cerr << "Unknown lexeme\n";
            exit(EXIT_FAILUERE);
        }
    }

    return tokens;
}

Теперь мы можем приврать код в вектор токенов с помощью этой функции. Осталась только функция main.
int main()
{
    std::string code = "main(form(text(hello())text1(new)))";

    std::vector<Token> tokens = tokenizer(code);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
    {
        Token token = tokens.at(i);
        
        if(token.type == TokenType::close_pra && i + 1 < tokens.size() && tokens.at(i + 1))
        {
            std::cout << "\n";
            i += 2;
        }

        else 
        {
            std::cout << token_to_string(token);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


optional* - для использования optional вам потребуется С++17 или новее.
